# Read data.json from HTML search flights file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a data.json file. I created an HTML file search to read the data.json file, but it does not work. Can I get help in creating a file that contains a search for flights that is in my Data Jenson file?

Thank you

This is my data.json file

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "City/Airport": "Aarhus",
      "Country": "Denmark",
      "IATA code": "AAR"
    },
    {
      "City/Airport": "Abadan",
      "Country": "Iran",
      "IATA code": "ABD"
    },
    {
      "City/Airport": "Abeche",
      "Country": "Chad",
      "IATA code": "AEH"
    }
}
```

This is my HTML search form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flight Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flight Search</h1>
<select name="from" id="from" type="search">
  <option value="">Select a city</option>
  <?php
    $data = require('./data.json');
    foreach ($data as $city) {
      echo '<option value="' . $city['iataCode'] . '">' . $city['city'] . ', ' . $city['country'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  
  <select name="to" id="to" type="search">
    <option value="">Select a city</option>
    <?php
    $data = require('./data.json');
    foreach ($data as $city) {
      echo '<option value="' . $city['iataCode'] . '">' . $city['city'] . ', ' . $city['country'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<script>
const data = require('./data.json');

const cities = [];

for (const city of data) {
  cities.push({
    name: city.City/Airport,
    country: city.Country,
    iataCode: city.IATA code
  });
}

const from = document.getElementById('from');
const to = document.getElementById('to');

from.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const iataCode = from.options[from.selectedIndex].value;
  const city = cities.find(city => city.iataCode === iataCode);
  document.getElementById('fromLabel').textContent = city.name;
});

to.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const iataCode = to.options[to.selectedIndex].value;
  const city = cities.find(city => city.iataCode === iataCode);
  document.getElementById('toLabel').textContent = city.name;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to fix errors that do not work on my local server, thank you

Comment: data.json I shortened the file and only took the top part of it because it's too big

Answer (score -1):

It is working now. I just want the field to include search not select. I could not modify the HTML file.

[image]